# Ionic-styled Twitter Bootstrap ever exists?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, ionic-framework

**Background:**
I am new to web programming. I learn to code and eventually manage to build a website at [www.rtest.org](http://www.rtest.org). I takes months to learn the html, css, javascript, jquery, php, mysql, and bootstrap. Recently, I decided to build an apps for my website. After some study, I feel that I like the Ionic framework very much. However, AngularJS is required in order to use the Ionic framework effectively. I can learn Angular too, yet it is too expensive for me to re-code my website (which heavily depend on jquery and bootstrap) to suit the app. To develop the app with Bootstrap? Probably no, because Bootstrap theme are too common, it has a 'website feel', and I want my app to have a 'native mobile view'.

**Question:**
So, are there any Bootstrap theme that look like Ionic? In other words, are there any front-end framework that ***LOOK like Ionic, but USE like Twitter-Bootstrap***?

I tried to search but I can't find any matches. May please suggest if you know if this framework ever exists.

Comment: do you want to recycle your jquery and bootstrap code on an ionic application? or i missunderstand you? if is the aspect of the application, just use bootstrap with angular.

Comment: i want to implement the app with minimal effort, and achieve maximum beauty. Since my website is coded in jquery and designed with bootstrap, then it will be nice if i can reuse all the programming codes and attributes (e.g. bootstrap classes & tags) from my website. In this case, i dont need to re-code for the app, and can easily "copy-paste" my original web codes to implement the new app... and the app will look like native app (ionic look nice in mobile device), not as similar as my website. This will save a lot of time, imagine if i need to re-code again and again for every update...

Comment: well a con of this is that ionic works directly with angular, so you can't use the tags of ionic, since you aren'r using it, also all the plugins that offers to use the API of android.

Comment: ya, that is the reason that i want something that "**LOOK**" like Ionic externally, but "**CODE**" like bootstrap, probably a Bootstrap that customized with Ionic CSS components. I understand that Ionic have js component such as actionSheet, popover, etc that used AngularJS, and I am searching for a framework that use Jquery, but look like Ionic. Haha, i guess it is hard to find, cause i hardly find any. nevermind, i guess it is hard to find... yet i guess it will be very useful, because jquery & bootstrap are very famous, and if this "Ionic theme bootstrap" exists, lot of ppl need it

Comment: Ohh well, stll you can use your styles on ionics, but your logic must be on angular. Also are many libraries for angular theme based on bootstrap. ionics just provides some support on mobile aspect, that can also be applied css with bootstrap